# How can I still do gsub even if there is a nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub

I have the following and it bombs out when the method comes up "nil"?  How can I default to no substtution in that case?

```
 message.gsub("{FirstName}", contact.first_name).
         gsub("{LastName}", contact.last_name).
         gsub("{Title}", contact.title).
         gsub("{Company}", contact.company_name.clear_company).
         gsub("{Colleagues}", colleagues.to_sentence).
```

For example, I get an error when contact.title is nil.  How can I prevent that in that instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you can try appending `.to_s` to each variable? ex. `contact.first_name.to_s`. If it is nil, then it will become `""`.

Comment: is there a way to include a default value, I tried using || "default" but it doesn't work....

Comment: Yes, it should work. I just tested in irb with ruby 1.9.2: "one two three".gsub("two", nil || "LOL"), and it returned "one LOL three"

Comment: Just tested in irb with ruby 1.9.2: nil.to_s => ""

Comment: What is the problem you're having now? You did the || "default" and what's happening?

Comment: I tried using debugger but can't find the problem...it's all in one line....should I still use to_s?

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble understanding what your question is. Can you perhaps rephrase your original question with the new information you've gathered?

Comment: hmmm...I am using ruby 1.8.7, not sure if that is causing it...?

Comment: I am retrying it -- it is in a cron job so takes a while, but it hasn't error out yet using the || "default" --- I had used || before and didn't see it do anything but maybe it actually is the right answer for now...

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a good place for a ternary operator.

```
.gsub("{Title}", contact.title ? contact.title : "default").
```

if the contact title exists then it will use it and if not it will use "default".

Comment: I just saw other comments on ternary but this explained it. Need to try it to see how it works. I think I understand.